# Word for a person who is overly demanding of artists

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, literary-english

I'm trying to recall the word used to describe someone tyrannically demanding of talent/artists/actors. A despot.

Singali?

Pretty sure it's the name of a character from a book. Maybe killed them in the book, not sure. Obviously I've never read it. Pretty common usage. "To be a ___".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you’re searching for "svengali".

> The word "[svengali](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/svengali)" has come to refer to a person who, with evil intent, dominates, manipulates, and controls a creative person such as a singer or an actor.
>
> source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svengali

Comment: Thank you! Just could not spell that so as to search for it.